# static method won't call inline basic_stream << operator of an enum

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, static-members

I've got this enum type determining a state of an object foo:

```
enum fooStatus
{
    DOWN = 0,
    TEMPORARY_DOWN = 1,
    UP = 2
};
```

For this fooStatus enum I've written a basic_ostream operator for backward translation from the enum to a readable form for logging like this:

```
template<
    typename CH,
    typename TRAITS
>
inline std::basic_ostream<CH, TRAITS>& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CH, TRAITS>& os,
    fooStatus& status
)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case DOWN:
            os << "DOWN";
            break;

        case TEMPORARY_DOWN:
            os << "TEMPORARY_DOWN";
            break;

        case UP:
            os << "UP";
            break;

        default:
            os << "UNKNOWN STATUS";
            break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Now, this worked fine, until I created a static member function of foo, where I wanted to print out all the statuses of all the foo objects I'd had stored.

foo.h:

```
static std::string get_all_statuses();
```

foo.cxx:

```
std::string get_all_statuses() {
    ... 
    std::ostringstream result;
    foreach(foo in fooStorage) { //<-- non c++ simplification
        result << foo->get_status() << ","; /* get_status returns the fooStatus enum type*/
    }
    return result.str();
}
```

Sadly, this 'get_all_statuses' static function call returns a string containing a number rather than the text defined in the << operator above. Applying the operator upon the member get_status() function in the very same foo.cxx file in foo's member function works just fine. I can't seem to understand some basics here and my colleagues failed to find a solution too.

Hence, my questions are rather two:

First, what is the exact logic behind this behaviour? (expecting something like a compiler not knowing the inline operator at the time of the static function compilation)

Secondly, what would be the best practice approach to make this work as expected?

Comment: You are not even writing where you put your op<< and if foo.cxx can see it. A self container testcase that people can see, compile and run for themselves to see what you see would be helpful.

Comment: Your operator is using a non-const reference for the rhs `fooStatus& status`. Without seeing it (since you didn't post it) I'm guessing no such reference is returned from `get_status()`. Change the rhs parameter to `const fooStatus& status`, or just `fooStatus status` (the latter preferred).

Comment: PlasmaHH: both the Enum definition and the op<< are in the same file. There are other member methods of foo in the foo.cxx which print the fooStatus correctly, hence I assume it's visible and included correctly.

Comment: WhozCraig: since I'm not sure, I'm trying it now, but wouldn't the change from `fooStatus& status` to `fooStatus status` just change the way it's handled, the later just copying the value instead of passing it by reference as in the original case? The missing `const` seems a good improvement to me for the code clarity and I thank you for your good eyes, though I can't see how it would help with the problem I'm having.

Comment: @SirGlorg You need to pass it by reference because...? You're not changing it, and it is an `int` (as far as you know) under the covers. it is going to perform better if you drop the reference *entirely* and just use pass-by-value in this case. Were it some *object* I would say use a const-reference, but it isn't; its an integral type under the hood.

Comment: Wou, WhozCraig - it helped, but now I'm second guessing, that the it might have been because I did not rebuild the library holding the template operator before... That would be certainly the main reason and I apologize for the puzzle...

Comment: Its a template (and a rather simple one) in a header. Rebuilding a lib shouldn't matter, as the implementation will be pulled into the compiling source including said-header (unless the static you're calling is in said-lib an the template changed since last-rebuild). I think you should be good for now changing that param to either a const-ref (as the answer below says) or just a by-value. Glad it helped. Glad it helped.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're absolutely right. I thought it was the rebuild because I couldn't see the bottom of the problem, but the change to the `const` reference certainly did help. Thank you. And as for the passing by reference -> It surely is for the performance reasons. I live in a believe that it should be more efficient no matter what, but that may not be the case for basic types such as the `int`. Thank you again for your insight.

Comment: @SirGlorg Before you mistakenly conclude passing-by-reference is some silver bullet, [read this](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/). Things aren't always as they appear. And for a trivial non-class `enum`, unless you specifically need to modify it as n in/out param, passing by value is the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably get_status returns a `fooStatus` by value, which can't be bound to a mutable reference in the signature of `operator<<`. You need to change `fooStatus&` to `const fooStatus&` in your overload of `operator<<`, which will bind correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

enum fooStatus
{
    DOWN = 0,
    TEMPORARY_DOWN = 1,
    UP = 2
};

template<
    typename CH,
    typename TRAITS
>
inline std::basic_ostream<CH, TRAITS>& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CH, TRAITS>& os,
    const fooStatus& status
)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case DOWN:
            os << "DOWN";
            break;

        case TEMPORARY_DOWN:
            os << "TEMPORARY_DOWN";
            break;

        case UP:
            os << "UP";
            break;

        default:
            os << "UNKNOWN STATUS";
            break;
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << TEMPORARY_DOWN;
    return 0;
}
```